# Assign a Value to a Customized Toolbar Item

Tags: arcobjects, vb.net, arccatalog

I have developed a main toolbar that uses windows forms and arcobjects to write to sde databases.

I am trying to extend the functionality of the toolbar to point to two different databases dependent on which item on the tool bar they choose. Each item has the same process and steps associated with them.

Is there a way to pass a value when using the AddItem() command, similar to an onClick event?

```
    Public Sub New()

        AddItem("tlb_Champ") *I would like to pass the database path when they choose this item vs the item below
        BeginGroup()
        AddItem("tlb_Dommage")
        BeginGroup()
        AddItem("tlb_Seismic")

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to first create your custom commands before adding them to the toolbar. To create a custom command you need to create a class that inherits from [ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.BaseClasses.BaseCommand](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Overview/000700000004000000/). You must override the `OnCreate` method in your implementation and then you override the `OnClick` method to add the code you want executing when the command is clicked.

Then you can add the command to your toolbar using one of the `AddItem` methods:

`AddItem(String)`        - Add an item using an identifier string

`AddItem(Guid)`          - Add an item using a Guid

`AddItem(Type)`          - Add an item by specifying the type

`AddItem(String, Int32)` - Add an item using a string identifier and subtype index

`AddItem(Guid, Int32)`   - Add an item using a Guid identifier and subtype index

`AddItem(Type, Int32)` - Add an item using a type and subtype index

`AddItem(UID)` - Add an item using a Unique Identifier Object (UID)